# MAGENTO - Where should I place SWF files?

Tags: flash, magento, module, directory

I have a swf file to record and play video in frontend. Where should I place it?
in `media/` or `skin/frontend/base/default/media/` or any other place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question of best practice, but really it should be accessible from anywhere if you want it to be. Generally files pertaining to a specific theme will go in the skin/ folder (under the appropriate theme name - example: skin/frontend/base/mytheme/), and general media files used throughout the site will go in media. You could even create a swf/ folder in your media folder and place it in there!